# Is it true that Cloudinary can't process an image from a rich text editor in Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is it true that Cloudinary can't process an image from a rich text editor in Gutenberg?

One of the external developers that I don't personally know made this statement and he said that that is the main reason why he locked the feature in Gutenberg to add the image inside of rich text editor.

It doesn't make sense to me that such a massive company wouldn't be able to come up with a solution for something like this.

I tried to google it around but didn't find any answers to this.

Any WordPress Devs that could give an answer to this maybe?

Comment: Did you try contacting the Cloudinary team and ask them about this yet? If there's anyone who can give you an official answer is them.

Comment: Thanks, will do :) Did you ever hear of something like this if you worked with WP?

Comment: My guess is that images inserted directly into a rich text editor are [base64 encoded](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/base64-images.html). If so then it makes sense that Cloudinary can't optimize these images as they're just strings of text, not image files sitting on a server folder. Not sure if that's how it works with the Gutenberg editor though (I was talking about rich editors in general) so you'll need to test whether Gutenberg converts these images into base64 encoded images or if it uploads said images to the server (I think it's the latter but, again, test yourself and see.)